# Scala 2.8 Actor design document? Akka design document?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, actor, akka

Is there a design document for Scala 2.8 Actors, like it is for 2.7?

[Scala Actors: Unifying Thread-based and Event-based Programming](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/128406/files/haller_tcs2008_accepted.pdf)

Is there one for Akka?

The "Scala Improvement Documents Library" doesn't mention Actors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update August 2012:

The [Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/) has vastly improved, and has now many details on its design and architecture.

[image: Actor System]

---

Original Answer (May 2010)

Regarding **[Akka](http://akka.io/)**, I didn't find a design document per se, but the recent blog post series "[Thinking Asynchronous - Domain Modeling using Akka Transactors](http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2010/03/thinking-asynchronous-domain-modeling.html)" from [Debasish Ghosh](http://www.blogger.com/profile/01613713587074301135) are close enough.

Here are some of the salient points in the implementation ..

1. **Akka is based on the let-it-crash philosophy**. You can design supervisor hierarchies that will be responsible for controlling the lifecycles of your actors. [...]
2. accounts is the handle to a `Map` that gets persisted in Redis. Here we store all accounts that the clients open hashed by the account number. [...]
3. With Akka you can also provide a restart hook when you repository crashes and gets restarted automatically by the supervisor. postRestart is the hook where we re-initialize the Map structure.
4. Akka uses multiverse, a Java based STM implementation for transaction handling. In the code mark your transactions using `atomic{}` and the underlying `STM` will take care of the rest.